# Subtraction with variable number of columns in matrix in R

Tags: r

I have what I think should be an easy problem, but I can't seem to figure out a good way to solve it.  I have a matrix that is created within a loop, and the number of columns in the matrix varies.  I would like to create a vector where each item in the vector is calculated as follows (x is the number of column in matrix):

```
vec[1] = mat[1,1] - mat[1,2] - mat[1,3] - mat[1,4] -...- mat[1,x]

vec[2] = mat[2,1] - mat[2,2] - mat[2,3] - mat[2,4] -...- mat[2,x]
```

This is easy enough with only two columns, and I figured out how to do it with 3 columns, but more than 3 I am stuck.  Here is an example of what I have so far:

```
 # Create 4 column matrix
 mat <- matrix(c(rep(1, 10),
                 rep(2, 10),
                 rep(3, 10),
                 rep(4, 10)), nc = 4)

 #Create 2 column matrix and calculate: column1 - column2
 mat.2col <- mat[,1:2]
 sapply(1:nrow(mat.2col), function(x) 
   diff(rev(c(mat.2col[x,1], mat.2col[x,2])))
 )

 # Create 3 column matrix and calculate: column1 - column2 - column3
 mat.3col <- mat[,1:3]
 sapply(1:nrow(mat.3col), function(x) 
   diff(rev(c(diff(rev(mat.3col[x,1:(ncol(mat.3col)-1)])),mat.3col[x,ncol(mat.3col)])))
 )
```

Any suggestion on how to accomplish subtracting each item in a matrix row, when the number of columns in a matrix varies?  Also, the order of subtraction matter (column 2 has to be subtracted from column 1, etc.).

Comment: @Frank I don't think it's a typo. Check the example `diff(rev(c(mat.2col[x,1], mat.2col[x,2])))`

Comment: No it's correct. `diff(rev(1:2))` is equal to `1 - 2`. Because `diff` reverses the args. Not sure why OP would reverse a reversing function to undo the effect, but it gives the right answer.

Comment: I edited the wording.  The pseudocode is correct, my wording is wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is what you're after:

```
mat[,1] - rowSums(mat[,-1])
```

Answer (score 4):

This will provide the additive differences for all columns from the first.

```
Reduce("-", as.data.frame(mat))
```

Comment: Thank you!  This is what I was looking for.

Comment: @BenBolker to each there own.  R seems to always have multiple ways to accomplish the same thing.

Comment: @Frank's answer is more of a shortcut/workaround. This is the direct translation of the OP's intent.

Comment: Yeah, my mind went to this first, too, though I prefer `Reduce("-", split(mat,col(mat)) )` -- coercing to data.frame is, in a sense, also a workaround.

Comment: `data.frame` is just forcing the method of `"-"`. It's matrix method won't treat columns as single elements. But in the end, we're giving the question too much credit. upvotes for all : )